# While I'm trying to set up django server using docker "docker-compose up" its giving Error like this

Tags: django, docker

```sh
$ docker-compose up
django-ambassador-main_redis_1 is up-to-date
Creating django-ambassador-main_db_1 ... error

ERROR: for django-ambassador-main_db_1  Cannot create container for service db: user declined directory sharing E:\Office\django-ambassador-main\.dbdata

ERROR: for db  Cannot create container for service db: user declined directory sharing E:\Office\django-ambassador-main\.dbdata
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Docker Desktop on Windows 10.

You have to add that folder to "Resources" -> "File sharing":

[image: Screenshot of Docker Desktop settings]